# How to implement combination of rules without repeatings in ebnf grammar?

Tags: python, ebnf, peg, grako

I am using [Grako EBNF/PEG parser](http://pythonhosted.org//grako/).

I know that EBNF syntax allows to grab expressions that satisfy one of given options:

```
(a | b | c)
```

Is there a similar part of syntax or a workaround that allows to grab expessions that are any combinations of `a`, `b` and `c` without repetitions so that valid expressions would be like:

```
a b c
b a c
a b
b c
b
none
```

but not like:

```
b b c
a a
```

?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to spell out the combinations in the rule.

Another way is to use a semantic action that checks for repetitions and raises `grako.exceptions.FailedSemantics` if it finds them. The parser's behaviour will be just as if the input hadn’t parsed.

Comment: Thanks for idea of using semantic actions. And how do I implement combinations `with` repetitions?

Comment: You can use ```{a | b | c}+``` (will you upvote/accept the answer?).